# One Vertical and One Horizontal RecyclerView in same layout and ImageView Toolbar Parallax Collapse animation

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, toolbar, parallax

I need to create the following layout on Android.

[image]

I found the following materials, [Link1](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView), [Link2](https://github.com/kanytu/android-parallax-recyclerview) and tried to use them but I can not, I can not do Vertical `RecyclerView` have your `wrap_content` size and make a horizontal scroll to the `ImageView` and `Toolbar` remain with the parallax effect and collapse.
Could help me in creating this layout and have the effect activated when performing the vertical scroll in the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts I used the following [lib](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView) and it worked. è simpler to use, provides several examples and a single component already got the desired effect, but must scroll content has to be greater than the empty screen space for the scroll take effect because it has not the bounce effect as in iOS.

The vertical RecyclerView is not necessary in the case created a fabric items which adds views of cards which serves content to scroll. So only use the horizontal scroll lower RecyclerView.
This does not compromise the functioning of ObservableScrollView scroll.